# invalid conversion from 'char' to 'char*' strcat function

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, char, strcat

So I have a function that takes in a file input character by character and forms the characters into sentences to be modified. One of the modifications to be done is to make a run on sentence in this instance. It will take two sentences and form a run-on sentences by removing the punctuation between them and concatenating them.

Here is my code:

```
void runOn(char sentence, ifstream & fin, int counter)
{
  char ch;
  int sentCounter = 0;

  bool sentenceEnd = false;
  while(sentCounter<=2)
  {
    char tempSent[SENT_LENGTH];;
    do
    {
      fin.get(ch);

      for(int i = 0; i<SENT_LENGTH;i++)
      {
        tempSent[i] = ch;
      }

      if(ch == '.' || ch == '?' || ch == '!')
      {
        sentCounter++;
        sentenceEnd = true;
      }
    }while(sentenceEnd == false);
    strcat(sentence,tempSent);
  } 
}
```

The counter passed is only used because the function should only run for the first two sentences.

When I attempt to compile, I get this error:

```
function.cpp:36:29: error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]
     strcat(sentence,tempSent);
```

Edit: I should add, I'm only allowed to use C style null terminated character arrays

Comment: `char` is a *single* character, `char*` is a pointer to character (possibly an array of) then prototype should be `char* sentence` (or an array of characters). Oh and BTW these aren't C++ strings

Comment: Why are you using old C-style strings (or in your case a single character)? Why not the standard [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) class which will make it much easier to handle strings in general?

Comment: I just edited my original post. I'm only allowed to use C-style strings in this instance, instead of std::string. I'm not very familiar with C-style strings myself, and would have used otherwise in a heartbeat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is very clear, `strcat` is declared as `char * strcat ( char * destination, const char * source );`, however, `sentence` is not `char*`, you must convert `sentence` from `char` to `char*`.

Since I don't know where `sentence` comes from, I can't give further advice, may be you should post the function which called the `runOn`.

Maybe you can simply change `void runOn(char sentence, ifstream & fin, int counter)` to `void runOn(char* sentence, ifstream & fin, int counter)`

See declaration of `strcat` [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/ as you can see strcat accepts `char *` not `char` in your function you need to take sentence as `char*`  then your function will work.